# Can and should I use JS AbortController like .NET CancellationToken?

Tags: javascript, .net, task, abortcontroller

I recently found out about [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) and its sibling [`AbortSignal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal) to register event listeners until I don't want it anymore.

When I look at the documentation, it looks surprisingly similar to .NET [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=net-7.0) and [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=net-7.0), the controller has `abort()` method, the signal has `aborted` property and even a `throwIfAborted()` method.

However I am not sure if it was designed to be used internally by APIs like `fetch` and `addEventListener` only or can I use it for my own APIs like this?

```
function doSomething(input, ct) {
   ct?.throwIfAborted();
   await this.doStuff();
   ct?.throwIfAborted();
   // ...
}
```

Is there anything I should notice coming from .NET background that I should be aware of?